# Create an Array Tree of Objects with different levels and positions

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a Array Tree of Objects with different levels and positions. In my opinion the parentId can create the level as in "children". The position can sort the items.

- Unlimited in levels and positions.

Can somebody help me out how I can achieve this?

I receive the following API data:

```
[ 
 { label: "Level one 1", id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0},
 { label: "Level two 1-1", id: 4, parentId: 1, position: 0},
 { label: "Level three 1-1-1", id: 9, parentId: 4, position: 1},
]
```

Here is an example how I want the data in the end:

```
const dataSource = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    position: 0,
    parentId: null,
    label: 'Level one 1',
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        position: 0,
        parentId: 1,
        label: 'Level two 1-1',
        children: [
          {
            id: 9,
            parentId: 4,
            position: 0,
            label: 'Level three 1-1-1',
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            parentId: 4,
            position: 1,
            label: 'Level three 1-1-2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    position: 1,
    parentId: null,
    label: 'Level one 2',
    children: [
      {
        id: 5,
        position: 0,
        parentId: 2,
        label: 'Level two 2-1',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        position: 1,
        parentId: 2,
        label: 'Level two 2-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    position: 2,
    parentId: null,
    label: 'Level one 3',
    children: [
      {
        id: 7,
        position: 0,
        parentId: 3,
        label: 'Level two 3-1',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        position: 1,
        parentId: 3,
        label: 'Level two 3-2',
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

Answer (score 2):

for this you can combine `map` method to redefine item in your array and `filter` to get only child of a parent object

```js
var data = [ 
 { label: "Level one 1", id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0},
 { label: "Level two 1-1", id: 4, parentId: 1, position: 0},
 { label: "Level three 1-1-1", id: 9, parentId: 4, position: 1},
];

var result  = data.map(elem => {
  elem.children = data.filter(item => item.parentId === elem.id);
  return elem;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a ingle loop approach with an object as reference for each node.

```js
const
    getTree = (data, root) => {
        const t = {};
        data.forEach(o => ((t[o.parentId] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(Object.assign(t[o.id] ??= {}, o)));
        return t[root].children;
    },
    data = [{ label: "Level one 1", id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0 }, { label: "Level two 1-1", id: 4, parentId: 1, position: 0 }, { label: "Level three 1-1-1", id: 9, parentId: 4, position: 1 }],
    tree = getTree(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is working. But it doesn't do anything with the position. Position 0, should be index 0. Position 1, should be index 1. How to sort that out?

Comment: what should be in pos 0 if no data is available?

Answer (score 0):

This solution first create a copy of each object, and stores it in a Map instance. I manually add the key `null` with value `{ children: [] }`, so we can handle/find the root object easily.

After creating the Map instance, I loop over each records. Fetch both the copy of the record itself and the parent. Then assign `parent.children` to an array if it's not present. Finally I assign the `record` as a child of `parent` based on its `position`.

```js
function recordsToTree(records) {
  const lookup = new Map(records.map(({ ...record }) => [record.id, record]));
  lookup.set(null, { children: [] });

  for (const { id, parentId, position } of records) {
    const record = lookup.get(id);
    const parent = lookup.get(parentId);
    
    parent.children ||= [];
    parent.children[position] = record;
  }
  
  return lookup.get(null).children;
}

console.log(
  recordsToTree([
    { label: "Level three 1-1-2", id: 3, parentId:    4, position: 1 },
    { label: "Level one 1",       id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0 },
    { label: "Level three 1-1-1", id: 9, parentId:    4, position: 0 },
    { label: "Level two 1-1",     id: 4, parentId:    1, position: 0 },
  ])
);
```

If `position` does not reflect the index of a child element you could use `parent.children.push(record)` instead of `parent.children[position] = record`.